# How to choose an appropriate error prefix?

Tags: command-line, error-handling, conventions

How can I figure out appropriate error prefixes to use when reporting various kinds of errors? Is there are guideline or overview of how these should be? I see patterns in many commands, but find it difficult to know which of these I should adapt in my own software.

By "error prefix" I mean a prefix of the kind `error:`, `usage:`, `fatal:`, `warning:`, etc. Sometimes there are also multiple of these prefixes.

Some real world examples are:

```bsh
$ ls non/existant/directory
ls: cannot access 'non/existant/directory': No such file or directory
```

```bsh
$ git status
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

```bsh
$ apt version
E: Invalid operation version
```

```bsh
$ gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Consider the person who is going to read the message, quite possibly from a log days after the event. The aim is to make is easy for them to resolve the issue (either as user, sysadmin, or developer). So providing information like program name, actual filenames (not just "file not found"), or the line number and actual bad data, and the action taken ("line ignored") is more important than exact categorisation.

Answer (score 1):

This is 100 % programmer decision. Some of these are based on severity of the issue and correspond with [syslog severity levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Severity_level) (like *error* or *warning*) but when it comes to the stdout/stderr messages these can be in any format author of the program likes.

Some libraries like GLib for example have their own [helper functions](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Message-Logging.html) to report warnings and errors in a "standardized" format but it isn't a system-wide policy.

`errno` and functions like `stderror` and `perror` provide the "suffixes" in the error messages, but that's just a human readable representation of the error code (e.g. `EPERM` -> *Operation not permitted*), the prefix is still "selected" by the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Since all programs have their own error reporting conventions, there is no single standard that you could expect to be able to parse out.  Best thing to do is just check the return code of the program (available with `$?` in bash).  If it is nonzero, then the program encountered an error.  You could then probably gather both the stdout and stderr from the program and include that in your reporting.

Comment: Hey, my goal is not to parse error messages, but rather to decide how I should report them in my own program https://github.com/fossegrim/midimap.

Comment: I see.  Well, there's no standard error format used across all programs, so it's up to you to design your messaging.  I would say that as long as you're consistent within the program, then things like the error prefix you use aren't super-important.